# trying to get item count for a model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, count

```
@if (Model.DonationDetail != null)
{
   @Model.DonationDetail.recipient.Count();
}
```

Is returning

Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

what is the best way to display a count of these items in recipient?

thanks

Comment: What does the recipient property look like? Is it a collection, or something that you could use Count() on? As I am not sure if that Error exactly pertains to that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<text> @Html.Encode(Model.DonationDetail.Recipient.Count()) </text>
```

Comment: it is this section of code, its the same line the compiler complained about. 
here is the model, DonationRecipient has no IEnumerable types inside.

` public class DonationDetail
    {
        public IEnumerable<DonationRecipent> recipient { get; set; }
    }
`

Comment: Are you looking for a count of the number of recipients? If so - what you have looks correct, have you tried debugging to see what your model looks like in the controller?

Comment: the models work fine because  i have a foreach later on in my code and i get the information from the items in Model.Donation.recipient
item.name.. etc all display on the page

ALSO: I got it to compile without any errors, but there should be a count of 1, it displays nothing.

Comment: So the things are being displayed fine? Or are you still getting the Compiler Error? If so, perhaps comment out that section to see if the arrow is still being thrown, or possibly do a search for Write.

Comment: i removed the @ and i get no compiler error
but there is nothing displayed for count even though i know there is 1 item because i see its properties